# use connectionstring from webconfig rather than dataset properties

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I built a dataset using the wizzard and added a connection in there.

I now want to use a connection string which is defined in my web config instead of whats set in the dataset.

I have the following code (i've taken a lot of stuff out you don't need to see)

> Partial Public Class downloaditems
>       Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
>
> ```
> Private dtmboFeed As dsmbo.mboFeedDataTable
> Private tamboFeed As New dsmboTableAdapters.mboFeedTableAdapter
> Private itemCount As Integer = 0
> Private changedItem As Boolean = False
> Private headSource As String
> Private footSource As String
> Private sideSource As String
> Private lastHead As String
> Private lastFoot As String
> Private lastSide As String
>
> Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
>     feedChecks()
>     If changedItem = True Then
>         If itemCount = "3" Then
>             savetodatabase(headSource, footSource, sideSource)
>         End If
>     End If
> End Sub
>
> Private Sub checkSite(ByVal URL As String, ByVal Type As String)
>
>     Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(URL)
>     request.UserAgent = ".NET Framework Test Client"
>     Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
>
>     Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
>
>     Dim sourcecode As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
>     Dim compareHead As Integer
>     Dim compareFoot As Integer
>     Dim compareSide As Integer
>
>     Select Case Type
>         Case "headSource"
>             headSource = sourcecode
>             compareHead = String.Compare(headSource, lastHead)
>         Case "footSource"
>             footSource = sourcecode
>             compareFoot = String.Compare(footSource, lastFoot)
>         Case "sideSource"
>             sideSource = sourcecode
>             compareSide = String.Compare(sideSource, lastSide)
>     End Select
>
>     If Not compareHead = "0" Then
>         changedItem = True
>     End If
>     If Not compareFoot = "0" Then
>         changedItem = True
>     End If
>     If Not compareSide = "0" Then
>         changedItem = True
>     End If
>
>     itemCount = itemCount + 1
>
> End Sub
>
> Private Sub feedChecks()
>
>     Dim lastImport As DateTime
>     dtmboFeed = New dsmbo.mboFeedDataTable
>     dtmboFeed = tamboFeed.GetCode()
>
>     For Each rFeed As dsmbo.mboFeedRow In dtmboFeed
>         lastImport = rFeed.LastImport
>         lastHead = rFeed.HeaderCode
>         lastFoot = rFeed.FooterCode
>         lastSide = rFeed.SideCode
>     Next
>
>     If lastImport > System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) Then
>         checkSite("http://www.xxx.me/sss/header.html", "headSource")
>         checkSite("http://www.xxx.me/sss/footer.html", "footSource")
>         checkSite("http://www.xxx.me/sss/sidenav.html", "sideSource")
>     Else
>         Exit Sub
>     End If
>
>
> End Sub
>
> Private Sub savetodatabase(ByVal HeaderCode As String, ByVal FooterCode As String, ByVal SideCode As String)
>
>     dtmboFeed = tamboFeed.GetData()
>     Dim rFeed As dsmbo.mboFeedRow
>
>     rFeed = dtmboFeed.NewmboFeedRow
>
>     rFeed.HeaderCode = HeaderCode
>     rFeed.FooterCode = FooterCode
>     rFeed.SideCode = SideCode
>     rFeed.LastImport = System.DateTime.Now
>     rFeed.Verified = "True"
>
>     dtmboFeed.AddmboFeedRow(rFeed)
>     tamboFeed.Update(dtmboFeed)
>
>     lblCode.Text = lblCode.Text & "All downloaded"
>
> End Sub End Class
> ```

**EDIT:**

Heres my updated code below as requested. I'm getting an error saying

```
Error   53  Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.
```

Code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim constring As String
        constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectString").ToString()
        tamboFeed.Connection = constring

        feedChecks()
        If changedItem = True Then
            If itemCount = "3" Then
                savetodatabase(headSource, footSource, sideSource)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: see the answer below. It is working.

Comment: well you missed the function brackets of ToString. And any error you got now ?

Comment: Error 53 Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'. (same error with the brackets)

Comment: first you mention ` Error 53 Value of type 'System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings'` and now you mention `  Error 53 Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'` The error changed from ConnectionStringSetting to System.Data.SqlClienht.SqlConnection ? and can you please show me your connection string in your webconfig.   add the ConnectString to your code

Comment: Sorry, you're right. The latest one string cannot be converted is the correct error now. - connection string: <add key="ConnectString" value="data source=server;initial catalog=database;persist security info=False;user id=adsadasda;password=asdsadasd;packet size=4096" />

Comment: use this `constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("YouconnectionStringNameinWebConfig").ConnectionString` hope that it will work

Comment: I have updated my answer, just use it.

Comment: I really appreciate all your help and patience. Unfortunately I'm still getting a: Error 53 Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'

Comment: I got the error and I have updated my answer, I'm 100% sure it will work now :)

Comment: Yeah I do, The error is on the line tamboFeed.Connection = constring

Comment: see my updated answer. The problem is that you have placed your connectionstring in the Appsettings section move it to the ConnectionString section as I mentioned in my answer. Then your code will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the connection string as

```
Dim constring as String
constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("YouconnectionStringNameinWebConfig").ConnectionString
```

Now first go to your DataSet Design View, Select the table,right click on tableAdapter and Change it's Connection modifier to Public ( see below picture ), now you can access adapter connection property in the codebehind.

```
tamboFeed.Connection = constring
```

See the below picture for changing access modifier.[image]

Picture Reference: [Link](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2007/05/26/changing-the-connectionstring-of-a-wizard-generated-tableadapter-at-runtime-from-an-objectdatasource.aspx)

**Updated answer:**
The problem is that you have placed you connection string in the AppSettings section in the webconfig, add your connection string to ConnectionString Section. See below code

```
    <connectionStrings>     
<add  name="ConnectString" connectionString="data source=server;initial catalog=database;persist security info=False;user id=adsadasda;password=asdsadasd;packet size=4096" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: But how do you tell the `dsmbo.mboFeedDataTable` to use it?

Comment: @Andomar I had edited my post and also add the code to change dataset connectionstring.

Comment: Thanks for this. Where am I adding the constring = config.... as it doesn't work in the actual page. Does it need to be on the databaset vb rather then my page code?

Comment: add it on the page where you want to change your connection string.

Comment: I get a Error 53 Value of type 'System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings' cannot be converted to 'String'.

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong.Post your code here. Use the ToString method at the end like this `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("YouconnectionStringNameinWebConfig").ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

tamboFeed.Connection is of type System.data.SqlClient.SqlConnection so cannot accept a string assignment. So long as the dataset connection modifier is set to Public, you can assign the connection string from the web.config in one line, as follows:

```
tamboFeed.Connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("YouconnectionStringNameinWebConfig").ConnectionString
```